# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) in react native project

Tags: react-native

I am building a react native project I get the following error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `SignInScreen`.

Here is my code.

```js
import React from 'react';

import { View,Image,StyleSheet,useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';

import Logo from'../../../assetss/images/logo.png';

import CustomInput from '../../components/CustomInput';

const SignInScreen =  () => {


     const {height} = useWindowDimensions();

    return (
        <View style= {styles.root}>
          <Image source={Logo} style ={[styles.logo, {height: height * 0.3}]}
           resizeMode="contain" /> 
          <CustomInput />
       </View>
 );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   root: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 20,
    },

   logo:{
    width: 1000,
    maxWidth: 1100,
    maxHeight: 200 ,
   }
})


export default SignInScreen
```

Answer (score 43):

There is a difference between `named exports` and `default exports`.

**Named Export**

Can be used for top level values of a module, e.g.

```js
export const fetch = () => {

}

export const Component = () => {
    return <></>
}
```

The above can be imported using

```js
import { fetch, Component } from "./MyModule"
```

Notice the curly braces.

**Default Export**

A default export can only be used *once* per file, e.g.

```js
const Component = () => {
    return <></>
}

export default Component;
```

The above can be imported using

```js
import Component from "./MyModule"
```

Notice that we have not used curly braces here.

The error message

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

tells us that we have mixed this up for some of our imports. Your imports for `View, Image, StyleSheet` and `useWindowDimensions` are correct. Hence, either `CustomInput` or `Logo` is not correctly imported (or exported; it depends on how we want to see it).

You are assuming `default exports` for both. Check if they are exported using `default export`.

If you do not want to use default exports, then you need to change your import statements to the following.

```js
import { CustomInput } from '../../components/CustomInput';
```

Furthermore, check that the import paths, e.g. `'../../../assetss/images/logo.png'` and `'../../components/CustomInput'`, are correct.

Comment: thanks for your help my probl/em is solved b/y just putting .js . For example import CustomInput from './../../components/CustomInput/CustomInput.js'

Answer (score 11):

In my case the problem was I created all components but didn't save the files. I don't use autosave, so I created all components, imported them to my Home component, but they were not saved so that error was thrown. Once I saved each file, the error disappeared.

Comment: That was exactly my case! lol

Answer (score 6):

**Faced while unit test in react**

Notices the same issue while writing unit test case using jest and react-testing-library.

**Problem**: It may be due to wrong way of mocking the component using jest.mock

**Problem Situation:**

```
jest.mock('./components/notes-list', () => {
  return {
    NotesList: () => <div data-testid='note-list-component'>Hello World</div>,
  };
});
```

**Solution**

```
jest.mock('./components/notes-list', () => {
  const NotesList = () => (
    <div data-testid='note-list-component'>Hello World</div>
  );

  return NotesList;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party here, but I just encountered this and the issue actually arose from an import that my IDE (VS Code) generated automatically for me as I was entering JSX.

```
// This next line is what got generated and caused the issue
//  WRONG  (Default exports):
import Modal from '@fluentui/react/lib/Modal';

// Here is what _should_ have been generated:
// ✅ RIGHT ✅ (named exports)
import { Modal } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Modal';


export const myComponent = () => {
  // ...

  return (
    <Modal isOpen={...}/>
      ...
    </Modal>
  );
```

As you can see from the code, the IDE generated a default import (no braces around `Modal`).  The lib actually exports the Modal component as a named export, and as a result, in the incorrect code, `Modal === undefined`.

This causes React to crank on about expecting a string or a class/function.  In my case, that lib (Modal) has no default export, so React reported getting `undefined`.

Sadly, it took a while to figure this out.  "It's only help when it's helpful" as my grandma used to say.  In this case the auto-import was *not* helpful - it happily threw me under the bus.  Unfortunately, React can't really report more about the issue either because, by time the call is made, the incorrect value is already passed.  All React does at that point is to say "that ain't right".

Type checking at development time also failed oddly as well - you can see from the pop-up that it's a named constant that's exported, but it's seen as the default import, which is wrong, so this ended up being found by manually stepping through the React code to pin it down.

Hope this helps other folks - check your imports from other libs to ensure you didn't get "helped"...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you had an index.js file in your CustomInput folder, so when you wrote

```
import CustomInput from './../../components/CustomInput';
```

it thought you wanted

```
import {CustomInput} from './../../components/CustomInput/index.js';
```

but really you wanted

```
import CustomInput from './../../components/CustomInput/CustomInput.js';
```

This error

> "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's
> defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of ..."

> shows up for many different types of errors that directly or
> indirectly eventually boil down to export/import default/named.
> Besides your case where it thought you were looking in index.js for a
> {named} in curly braces export/import, you can also get that error
> message if you accidentally misspell your named import, for example:
> import {Flatlist} with a lowercase l instead of import {FlatList} with
> an uppercase L.

Answer (score 1):

So, I had the same error but for a totally different reason.

I was sending an errorBoundary component as a prop from another component.

```
<SomeComponent key={key} errorBoundary={<ErrorBoundary />} />
```

and then inside `SomeComponent`

```
return (
    <div ... >
      {ErrorBoundaryComponent ? (
        <ErrorBoundaryComponent>{componentWithProps}</ErrorBoundaryComponent>
      ) : (
        componentWithProps
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

The problem was that I was sending the ErrorBoundaryComponent as a *rendered* prop (jsx)

the fix was sending the errorBoundary as such:

```
<SomeComponent key={key} errorBoundary={ErrorBoundary} />
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message was not pointing me to the exact line/component/cause of the issue, I ended up just deleting sections of the problem code until I was able to pinpoint exactly which component was causing the issue.

In my case, the issue was of course mixed up imports as well... I was able to fix it by changing:

```
import CustomTooltip from '..';
```

to

```
import { CustomTooltip } from '..';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help my problem is solved by just putting .js .
For example:

```
import CustomInput from './../../components/CustomInput/CustomInput.js
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have shown, it seems like assets is spelt wrong. You can check if the actual folder is spelt like that.

Answer (score 0):

`react-icons` updated then throwed error 500 on production environment (whole website). It was not updating locally, and in two different environments.

Fix was:

Change

```
{...
        "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
...}
```

to

```
{...
        "react-icons": "4.3.1",
...}
```

`package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

For future people that come here,
Sometimes your IDE needs a hot reload/complete restart
In my case i use vsCode and in there if you enter (Ctrl+Shift+P), youopen a dialog box,There search for Developer:Reload window and enter it
THis will reload you IDE , and u can even try stopping your project and restarting it, or maybe even close your IDE.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was two files with same names in one directory `Footer.tsx` and `Footer.scss`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had this error for a different reason,I was ***importing files from the wrong locations,***
but everything else was alright.
You can identify this issue if your file runs independently but not work while importing it.